# Move substring to front of string

Tags: python, pandas, substring

I have a field "Numbers" that can have a value such as:

"01-02-03-04-Zero"

I want to change the substring "Zero" to "00" and move it to the front of the string, so that the result is:

"00-01-02-03-04"

Not all rows contain this "Zero" substring so I only want to perform this on fields that do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regex`. In this approach you can replace `Zero` with `00` if exist.

```
import re

def change_Zero(st):
    # If we find '-Zero', we replace all strings with '00' that add to the first part. 
    # with '\1' access to first part
    return re.sub(r"(.*)(-Zero)", r"00-\1", st) 

print(change_Zero("01-02-03-04-Zero"))
print(change_Zero("01-02-03-04-05"))
```

Output:

```
00-01-02-03-04
01-02-03-04-05
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to split the string to a list, find the indexes where "Zero" is, remove them, and add to "00" to the front of the list. Finally joint the list back to a string.

```
s = "01-02-03-04-Zero"
s_split = s.split("-")
zero_idxs = [n for n, elem in enumerate(s_split) if elem == "Zero"]

for idx in zero_idxs:
    s_split.pop(idx)

s = "-".join(["00"] * len(zero_idxs) + s_split)
```

This solution will work for any number of "Zero"s in the string.